# Remove Ubuntu from SSD and Install Windows 10

Tags: boot, ssd

I know there are similar questions already floating around the magical interweb, but I have quite a specific issue.

I built a new PC just yesterday, but decided not to go for an optical drive since I haven't used the one on my laptop in years. I figured the best way to install Windows then would be to boot Ubuntu from a flash drive, download Windows from there, and then install it onto the SSD. However, I encountered problems with the storage space on the flash drive(s) I was using, and accidentally ended up installing Ubuntu onto the SSD.

Now I have a bootable Windows OS on my flash drive, but cannot install it as the SSD is not formatted correctly. I assume I'm going to need to boot Ubuntu again, partition the SSD, and then install Windows from there? How do I do this? I'm tearing my hair out...

Answer (score 4):

You don't need anything once you have bootable windows usb.

boot from your usb and then at this point during installation, detele all the partitions. This will give you a big unallocated space where you can install windows.

There is no need to care about partitioning tables (i.e GPT or MBR). Windows installation will take care of it.

**Note:** This image is just for showing the option of deleting a partition. Your actual partition size will be different. It will have a `efi or system reserved partition` (~ <= 500 MB) , a big `ext4 partition` and a `swap partition` (~ 4-10 GB).

You have to delete everything until you get a big unallocated space.

I could not find an exact image with ubuntu partitions.

[image]

Comment: I don't believe the image shows a system with Ubuntu installed onto it, nor that Windows will take care of the partitioning itself. Therefore I downvoted. My experience is that the Windows 10 installer is unable to delete nor create new partitions so long an EXT4 formatted partition is connected.

Comment: I tested it myself and you are right, this method works. I've changed my vote.

Answer (score 0):

Run `gparted`, and format the drive to FAT32.
If it's not installed, run `apt-get install gparted` from terminal.
It will be accessible in the Ubuntu system tools menu or just by typing `sudo gparted`.